# how to define rules for some element with name like user[id] in query validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i one working on rails and rails follows some naming convention of input elements, i am not able to validate my form using query validation.

my form is like this

```
<form method="post">
<input id="user_id" name="user[id]" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value ="login" />
</form>

var myrules = {
user[id] : {
required : true
}
};
```

its not working this way :(

how can i define rule for input for name 'user[id]', as jquery create some variable based on the name of the elements, what should be the name of variable which jquery validator will create for this element

Answer (score 1):

this should work like this

```
rules : {
"user\[id\]" : {
required : true
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the name of the input (in this case user[id]) in quotes

```
var myrules = {
"user\[id\]" : {
required : true
}
};
```

Learn [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29)

Comment: we need to use escape sequence and not [ directly

Answer (score 0):

you missed quotes

Try this

```
rules : {
"user\[id\]" : {
required : true
}
};
```

Comment: @rajansoft1 in our project it works , ok i updated code